"New pieces draw something different from Phillip"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 18)

(In the rehearsal room)


'Morning gentlemen (the choristers),' Phillip (the choirmaster) says this morning, the usual tentative smile lifting his cheeks.
William (one of the choristers, main character) spots sheets of pristine music on top of Phillip's folder. Something new. William has noticed new pieces draw something different from Phillip; a lightness, a gentle spirit of adventure. Rehearsing things that have been sung here for two hundred years, William wonders if the chapel ever thinks, Not this one again!

I take "new pieces draw something different from Phillip" to mean something like "new pieces elicit something different from Phillip", right? In some respect I think the sentences "I don't see why I should draw comfort from the fact that I'm paid in ten days' time. How do I manage for food in the meantime?" support this notion.

You have it right. It is pulling some response or emotion out of someone in the way you would pull water up from a well.

Or you could take comfort from the fact that you will draw your wages in ten days' time. The verb draw can be used in a wide range of contexts.

What is the question? The understand the meaning of the sentence, where is the confusion?
